# Prolog: find the last index of an element in a list

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a list `[1,2,1,3,2,0,8,3,1]`,I want to find the index of the last 3 which is `7`, How to do it in prolog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
last(List, Needle, Ret) :- last1(List, Needle, 0, -1, Ret).

last1([H | T], N, Idx, Acc, Ret) :- Idx2 is Idx + 1, (H == N, !, last1(T, N, Idx2, Idx, Ret); last1(T, N, Idx2, Acc, Ret)).
last1([], _, _, Acc, Acc).
```

This traverses the whole list, maintaining the index of the last needle seen. Is this homework?